# How to extract text for a specific class name followed by specific text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect webdata using BeautifulSoup in Python. I am specifically trying to extract car features of different types. For example, in the html code pasted below, I am trying to extract 'Remote start', Navigation system' and 'Heated steering wheel' as 'Convenience' features. Could someone please let me know how to extract and store features for each such category?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code rather you can post formatted code.

Comment: Please include what research you have carried out and your current coding attempt indicating what isn't working with your current code. Guidance on posting is available via [ask] and [mcve] and you are welcome to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```py
import bs4
your_source_code = "<html>..."
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(your_source_code, "html.parser")

result = {}

for group in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "details-feature-list--normalized-features"}):
    result[group.find("h2", {"class": "cui-heading-2"}).text] = [itm.text for itm in group.find_all("li", {"class": "details-feature-list__item"})]
```

result is a dict like:
`{"Convenience": ["Remote Start", "Navigation System", "Heated Steering Wheel"]}`

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I was confused about extracting the feature categories (e.g., 'Convenience').